# How can I get a breakdown of different salt contents in a fertilizer solution?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, salt

I am experimenting a lot with hydroponics i.e. growing plants in a liquid solution. From time to time, I would like to do a check on what is the current salt level for major salts (ions) in parts per million (ppm) of my fertilizer solution.

For instance, Calcium, Nitrate, Nitrite, Fe, etc. would be some nice measurements that I would like to tabulate. For instance, I use [this device](https://www.robesol.nl/en/hi758-checker-for-calcium-in-salt-water.html) for measuring calcium level.

Is there a general method/ device that I could use to get a breakdown of commons ions in plant fertilizer (NH4, K, Ca, Mg, P, S, etc.). Even if I can just get N-P-K, that'd do too.